# How to test partial with Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

In a normal view spec file I can test the view with Capybara.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'site/login' do
  subject { page }
  before { visit login_path }
  it { should have_selector('#login form') }
end
```

With Rspec I can test the parital.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'site/sidebar' do
  it "displays the login form" do
    render :partial => "site/sidebar"
    expect(rendered).to match /form/
  end
end
```

Also with Capybara I can test the view like

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'site/sidebar' do
  let!(:rendered) { render :partial => "site/sidebar" }
  let(:page) { Capybara::Node::Simple.new(rendered) }
  it { page.should have_selector('form') }
end
```

Last one seems like working but feels kinda hacky. Is there any method exists in Capybara such thing like `visit_partial`? I thought I can find something similar in `Capybara::Driver::Base` but I couldn't find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hacky method looks fine to me. If you had a lot of partials you could use a shared context:

```
shared_context "Rendered partial" do
  let!(:rendered) { render :partial => partial }
  let(:page) { Capybara::Node::Simple.new(rendered) }
  subject { page }
end

describe "My partial" do
  let(:partial) { "site/sidebar" }
  include_context "Rendered partial"
  it { should have_selector('form') }
end
```